# C# API Web Request with JSON and Files

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, multipartform-data

I have this more complicated web request in C# which involves a File upload. I keep receiving 422 Unprocessable Entity error.
Basically this is the JSON structure that is required in the body of the request.

```
{
  "title":"abc",
  "publisher":
  {
    "city":"J Town",
    "year":2021
  }
  "File":"???",
  "Shed":[
     {
       "country":"NZ",
       "postcode":12345
     } 
   ]
}
```

What I have written is the following (I converted the file path to byte).

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api-abc.com/upload");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Token", "3SHFHBVRH87BHDBGV");
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"D:/abc.pdf");

var root = new RootObject()
{
    upload = new UploadDoc()
    {
        title = "Test 321",
        Publisher = new List<publishers>
        {
            new recipients()
            {
                city = "J Town",
                year = 2021
            }
        },
        file = $"Basic { Convert.ToBase64String(bytes) }",
        Shed = new []
        {
            new
            {
                country = "NZ",
                postcode = 12345
            }
        }
    }
};

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    var book = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    { 
        root
    });

    streamWriter.Write(book);
}

var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Which part did I do wrong?

Appreciate the help in advance :)

Comment: i'm afraid that's mostly dependent on the api you're trying to access. if you get a specific error message alongside the 500, please share it. i recommend reading their manual and contacting their support.

Comment: You probably shouldn't publish the token online. Usually you wouldn't put it in source code either.

Comment: It seems you should POST just a content-type application/json and use streamWriter.Write(root); instead of book

Comment: @user1344783 nope, does not work. Did I do the File parameter right?

Comment: Sorry, I meant streamWriter.Write(root.upload);